# Error al ejecutar pynput.mouse en visual studio code pero en cmd no

Tags: python

mi problema es que cuando quiero ejecutar el siguiente codigo en visual studio code:

> from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
>
> import msvcrt
>
> mouse = Controller()
>
> print(f'chinchinchan: {mouse.position}')
>
> mouse.position = (10,20) print(f'chinchinchinchan {mouse.position}')
>
> mouse.move(5, -5)
>
> mouse.press(Button.left) mouse.release(Button.left)
>
> mouse.scroll(0,2)
>
> msvcrt.getch()

pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\echea\OneDrive\Programación\prueba.py", line 1, in 
> from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'

pero al ejecutar desde cmd con:

> python prueba.py

se ejecuta el codigo, cual es el problema?, ayer yo podia ejecutarlo y ahora ya no
tengo version actualizada de pip y python y yo ya instale pynput, encima lo reinstale

Comment: Tienes 2 o mas versiones de Python instaladas?

Comment: @DanteS. como asi? como veo mis versiones que tengo? porque yo se que tengo la 3.10.4 que la instale desde python.org y otra que es la misma que instale desde microsoft store pero la misma version

Comment: Mmmmm, no se como podrias ver eso. Pero es posible que el Visual Studio Code ejecute la version descargada de Microsoft mientras el cmd ejecute la otra o viseversa. Y el modulo no lo tengas instalado en "ambas versiones"

Comment: @DanteS. entonces que hagp, alguna idea?

Comment: Prueba con desinstalar una de las dos versiones o revisar la configuracion del Visual Studio Code para ver si le indicas en alguna parte que version de Python usar.

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias ya lo resolvi <3

Comment: De nada UnHUmano c: